# how can i stop a php page from loading when its taking too long

Tags: php

i have a php page which auto refreshes itself after 10 seconds. Some time the page takes too long to load as its fetching data from external urls . How can i stop execution of the script after 10 seconds and then reload the page.

Answer (score 2):

1. fetch external data separately from request (e.g cron)
2. combine [set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) and register_shutdown_function

Answer (score 0):

- restart Apache server
- kill php process
- [set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) in your script above neuralgic piece of code